# Django import-export how to add current admin user to model

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to make [import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) select current/save user(defined as "author" field in model)

I tried this(save_model)  but it doesn't work(I think because of resource class)

```
class KWResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:

        model = KW
        import_id_fields = ('Keyword',)
        fields = ('Keyword',)


    searchess = fields.Field(attribute='searches', column_name="Avg. Monthly Searches (exact match only)")
    compp = fields.Field(attribute='comp', column_name="Competition")
    cpcc = fields.Field(attribute='cpc', column_name="Suggested bid")        

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

How to get id of admin user that initiated import here?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, not sure if it's the best solution but it works:

```
class KWResource(resources.ModelResource):
....
....
   def before_import(self, dataset, dry_run, *args, **kwargs):
       li = []
       li.append(kwargs.pop('user', 1))
       dataset.insert_col(0, li, 'user')
       return super(KWResource, self).before_import(dataset, dry_run, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this later, you can access the current django user in a hook on your Resource. There's a 'user' in the **kwargs.

```
def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
    row['author'] = kwargs['user'].id
```

More detail here:
[django-import-export assign current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952887/django-import-export-assign-current-user/56395976#56395976)

Comment: This works great in the admin section but not when using a custom form. Any ideas?