# django-import-export assign current user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-import-export

Trying to assign added_by user while creating an instance and want to create another model instance referring to the current instance

views.py

```
class ImportFarmersView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self,request,org_slug=None,format=None,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer=TmpFileUploadSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(data=serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        entries=serializer.validated_data['file']

        profile_resource=ProfileResource()
        dataset=Dataset()
        imported_data = dataset.load(open(entries.temporary_file_path(),'rb').read(),'xls')
        result = profile_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

        if result.has_errors():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        profile_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

resources.py

```
class ProfileResource(resources.ModelResource):
    created_at=fields.Field(readonly=True)
    updated_at=fields.Field(readonly=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        skip_unchange=True
        report_skipped=False
        import_id_fields=('slug','email')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know how to use get_resource_kwargs to allow passing request to resource if that could solve the problem https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/pull/457

Answer (score 5):

I used an alternate solution to the `before_import_row` answer proposed by @Jagu.

The reason why I did not want to use the `before_import_row` solution is because it forces me to create a field attribute for the resource. In addition, during the import process in the admin page, my users will potentially be confused with the fields that are required by the importer when it says: `This importer will import the following fields: field1, field2, autofield1, autofield2`. Instead I would rather prefer it to say: `This importer will import the following fields: field1, field2`.

Let's get on with the solution.

Suppose I have this model:

```
class LotNumber(models.Model):
    lot_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        primary_key=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

I will designate the `created_by` attribute as an *auto-populated* field.

Now here's what my resource class looks like:

```
class LotNumberResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = LotNumber
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
        fields = (
            'lot_number',
            'is_active',
        )

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, **kwargs):
        instance.created_by = kwargs['user']
```

As you can see, in my `Meta` block, I only have to specify `lot_number` and `is_active`. However, what method I chose to override is `after_import_instance`. At first I tried to use `before_import_row` but modifying the row did not auto-populate the `created_by` field. After digging into the source code, I noticed that that the method `get_or_init_instance` is called after the `before_import_row` method (see source code [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L639)), which fetches the model instance using my defined resource class (see source code [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/instance_loaders.py#L28)). Therefore, if the resource class did not list the auto-populated field in the `fields` attribute, the instance would never fetch that field.

Comment: Really awesome answer. Thanks for the extra details as well. Prost!

Comment: Thank you. Though, after looking at the source code links, it looks like the code has updated since my answer so I will modify the links to the specific lines where the functions are called.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current django user in the before_import_row hook on resources.ModelResource. There's a 'user' in **kwarg.

So in your case it would look something like

```
class ProfileResource(resources.ModelResource):
    ...
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['added_by'] = kwargs['user'].id
```

If you drop a breakpoint() in there and have a look at kwargs you'll see something like this (note that the User record is wrapped in a SimpleLazyObject):

```
-> row['added_by'] = kwargs['user'].id
(Pdb) kwargs
{'file_name': 'ImportDatasetWorking.csv', 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: 
Kumar>>}
```